# Printing a variable value with the name of another variable

Tags: bash

Suppose I have the following 2 variables:

```
color=black
round_black_car=IGK47546
```

Is it possible to print `IGK47546` with the variable `color`?

`echo ${round_${color}_car}` doesn't work. It gives me `bad substitution` error.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #6](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Evaluating_indirect.2Freference_variables) for a best-practices approach. (`eval` is **absolutely not** a best-practices approach; [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) goes into reasons why it's best avoided).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use eval expression combine with `backslash` to perform the replacement.

```
$ color=black
$ round_black_car=IGK47546
$ eval echo \${round_${color}_car}
IGK47546
```

Comment: This is not a safe practice, as it parses data as code -- a key component in injection attacks, privilege escalation attacks (when one can provide data used by scripts run with different permissions), and other kinds of security vulnerabilities. Consider the case of `color='}$(rm -rf ~)${'` as an illustrative example.